# Prestashop 1.5.6 - Add a custom field in Admin Product Page

Tags: prestashop, http-status-code-403, prestashop-1.5

I have been trying to introduce a new custom field in Admin Product page but got a weird error. Actually this field has the same text area type as the existing ones. **If I enter a plain text, it works fine** but if I enter anything starts with an opening angle bracket (<) it gives me a 403 forbidden error. I already checked permission of folders and files.

This is what I have done.

1. New db field
   [image]
2. ProductCore class. Made changes wherever 'description' is referenced because they are pretty much the same thing.
   [image]
3. Information.tpl modified to display this new field.
4. This is how Admin Product page looks like after the change. As you can see, a plain text can be saved without any issue.
   [image]
5. If I type in any html tag, which starts with an angle bracket, then save, I get a 403 error, whereas an existing textarea such as Description in the screen is totally fine.
   [image]

[image]

I have checked permission of files and folders and error logs but couldn't find any clue. Anyone got an idea? Please help!

**information.tpl**

```
        <tr>
            <td class="col-left">
                {include file="controllers/products/multishop/checkbox.tpl" field="description" type="tinymce" multilang="true"}
                <label>{l s='Description:'}<br /></label>
                <p class="product_description">({l s='Appears in the body of the product page'})</p>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    {include file="controllers/products/textarea_lang.tpl" languages=$languages
                    input_name='description'
                    input_value=$product->description
                    }
                <p class="clear"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="col-left">
                {include file="controllers/products/multishop/checkbox.tpl" field="alternate_item" type="tinymce" multilang="true"}
                <label>{l s='Alternate Item:'}<br /></label>
            </td>
            <td style="padding-bottom:5px;">
                    {include file="controllers/products/textarea_lang.tpl"
                    languages=$languages
                    input_name='alternate_item'
                    input_value=$product->alternate_item}
                <p class="clear"></p>
            </td>
        </tr>
```

**textarea_lang.tpl**

```
<div class="translatable">
{foreach from=$languages item=language}
<div class="lang_{$language.id_lang}" style="{if !$language.is_default}display:none;{/if}float: left;">
    <textarea cols="100" rows="10" id="{$input_name}_{$language.id_lang}" 
        name="{$input_name}_{$language.id_lang}" 
        class="autoload_rte" >{if isset($input_value[$language.id_lang])}{$input_value[$language.id_lang]|htmlentitiesUTF8}{/if}</textarea>
    <span class="counter" max="{if isset($max)}{$max}{else}none{/if}"></span>
    <span class="hint">{$hint|default:''}<span class="hint-pointer">&nbsp;</span></span>
</div>
{/foreach}
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var iso = '{$iso_tiny_mce}';
    var pathCSS = '{$smarty.const._THEME_CSS_DIR_}';
    var ad = '{$ad}';
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You must override the ProductCore class NOT modify ProductCore class

```
class Product extends ProductCore 
{
   public $alternate_item;

   public function __construct($id_product = null, $full = false, $id_lang = null, $id_shop = null, Context $context = null)
   {
         self::$definition['fields']['alternate_item'] = array('type' => self::TYPE_HTML, 'lang' => true, 'validate' => 'isCleanHtml');
         parent::__construct($id_product, $full, $id_lang, $id_shop, $context);
   }
}
```

The override class must be placed in **override/classes** folder or **yourmodule/override/classes**

When you override a class you must delete **cache/class_index.php**

Comment: Hi fito, I have tried everything you suggested but still got the same 403 error. I don't really understand why it is happening. Do you have any other idea? It must be something to do with those HTML tags..

Comment: I got a feeling that I should do something with AdminProductsController.php as well?

Comment: i just put some code of information.tpl as well as textarea_lang.tpl ..thanks for your time and help! please have a look

Comment: It seems to be a file permission problem. Check your prestashop installation files and directories permissions.